# converting from int to hex

Tags: c#, string, hex

I want to convert some ints to hex,but i'm getting something like this : "?|???plL4?h??N{" from 12345. Why?

```
int t = 12345;

System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider ano = new
System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

byte[] d_ano = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(t.ToString());
byte[] d_d_ano = ano.ComputeHash(d_ano);

string st_data1 = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(d_d_ano);
string st_data = st_data1.ToString();
```

I'm using it in window form,not in console.

Comment: What makes you think that that will convert an int to hex?

Comment: MD5 is a _hashing_ algorithm. It will not return the Hex value of an integer.

Comment: So it's not neccesery? I don't understand.I should only convert int to string using Babak way?

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to accomplish? "Hex" is a hexadecimal notation of a number, when the number is written as a human-readable string. Is it just the string you need? If yes, then you don't need any MD5.

Comment: But i want to change my int into another number, which user don't know. I only want to get hex of new number...

Answer (score 9):

To convert a number to hex, just use:

```
integerValue.ToString("X")
```

Answer (score 5):

Why are you using encryption if all you want to do is conversion?

For the actual conversion, use this snippet

```
int myNumber = 42;
String myHexNumber = myNumber.ToString("X");
```

Comment: @Oded: Because this answers the question.  The question wasn't "How do I convert an integer to a hex string?" but "Why am I getting the results I'm getting."

Comment: @Ben Voigt - I commented when the only thing in the answer was the first line.

Comment: @Oded: I saw that.  My point is that not a single other post here answers the singular question "Why?".  Only Babak explained that the code shown is encrypting the value (it's a hash function, so it's one-way encryption, but it is nonetheless encryption).

Answer (score 3):

```
value.ToString("X") is all you need
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int t = 12345;
Console.WriteLine("{0:X4}", t);
```

no?

Answer (score 2):

use `Convert.ToString(intValue, 16);`

**Edit:** this way can be used in all bases like `Convert.ToString(intValue, 2)`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to convert int to a hex string.

```
int t = 12345;
string hex = t.ToString("x");
```